# "Invalid Syntax" when using Sympy for Integration

Tags: python

I am trying to use Sympy to integrate a function but I get the "invalid syntax" error on the line containing the PFunction definition. I tried the exact same syntax with a more simpler function (ie. x^2) using method 1 and it solved that one just fine so what could the issue be here? I also tried method 2 but the same issue persists.

Method 1:

```
from sympy.interactive import printing
printing.init_printing(use_latex = True)
import numpy as np
from sympy import Eq, dsolve, Function, Symbol, symbols
import sympy as sp

T = 1000 #Temperature in (K)
k = 1.381E-23 #Boltzman's constant
maxen = 7*T*k #Max energy in system
cone = 2/((k*T)**(3/2)) #Constant infront of the Maxwellian distribution function

Ein = sp.Symbol('symsx')
MaxD = cone*np.sqrt(symsx/pi)*np.exp((-symsx/(k*T)) #Define Maxwellian distribution function
PFunction = sp.integrate(MaxD) #Integrate function to get probability-error function
```

print(PFunction)

Method 2: (Explicitly defining these as functions)

```
from sympy.interactive import printing
printing.init_printing(use_latex = True)
import numpy as np
from sympy import Eq, dsolve, Function, Symbol, symbols
import sympy as sp

T = 1000 #Temperature in (K)
k = 1.381E-23 #Boltzman's constant
maxen = 7*T*k #Max energy in system
cone = 2/((k*T)**(3/2)) #Constant infront of the Maxwellian distribution function

Ein = sp.Symbol('symsx')
MaxD = Function('MaxD')
PFunction = Function('PFunction')
MaxD = cone*np.sqrt(symsx/pi)*np.exp((-symsx/(k*T)) #Define Maxwellian distribution function
PFunction = sp.integrate(MaxD) #Integrate function to get probability-error function

print(PFunction)
```

Comment: Count your parentheses on the previous line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me correct your code

```
from sympy.interactive import printing
printing.init_printing(use_latex = True)
import numpy as np
from sympy import Eq, dsolve, Function, Symbol, symbols
import sympy as sp

T = 1000 #Temperature in (K)
k = 1.381E-23 #Boltzman's constant
maxen = 7*T*k #Max energy in system
cone = 2/((k*T)**(3/2)) #Constant infront of the Maxwellian distribution function

Ein = sp.Symbol('symsx')
MaxD = Function('MaxD')
PFunction = Function('PFunction')
MaxD = cone*np.sqrt(symsx/pi)*np.exp((-symsx/(k*T))) #Define Maxwellian distribution function
PFunction = sp.integrate(MaxD) #Integrate function to get probability-error function

print(PFunction)
```

You need to add one parenthesis to the `MaxD` line